# When I Publish my project in iis log4net doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, logging, web

When I debug it on Visual studio it works perfectly, but When I try to put it on my IIS directory it doesn't:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

   <configuration>
     <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
     </configSections>
     <log4net>
        <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
          <param name="File" value="C:\\Users\\leandro\\Desktop\\Caderneta.log"/>
          <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
          <appendToFile value="true" />
          <rollingStyle value="Size" />
          <maxSizeRollBackups value="3" />
          <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
          <staticLogFileName value="true" />
          <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%n%n%d [%t] %-5p %c %n  %m%n"/>
          </layout>
        </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="Error" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
     </root>
   </log4net>
   <system.web>
     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  <webServices>
    <protocols>
      <add name="HttpPost"/>
       <add name="HttpGet"/>
    </protocols>
  </webServices>

</system.web>

</configuration>
```

First I tried just to put Caderneta.log on param name, but it doesn't looks been created.
The path on my server exists for `C:\Users\leandro\Desktop\Caderneta.log`, but it still not creating the file Caderneta.

Comment: What account is IIS running under. It likely doesn't have permission to your desktop

Comment: If you create the file in the Public desktop instead of your desktop you may succed, for example: C:\\Users\\Public\\Desktop\\Caderneta.log

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Find that folder in windows explorer and give security permissions to the following local users if they exist:

NETWORKSERVICE

IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool